# prevent windows 10 from going to sleep while no user is logged in

Tags: windows, sleep, hibernate, remote, energy

I installed windows 10 LTSC on a desktop to use it as a server.
The plan is to use the server for a project that needs a fiberoptics connection, so the server would be at a remote location. Now what I see is that the server just sleeps/hibernates when no one is logged in even when the powerplan says never go to sleep as administrator.

Is there a way to prevent windows to go to sleep/hibernation when no one is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

> Now what I see is that the server just sleeps/hibernates when no one
> is logged in even when the powerplan says never go to sleep as
> administrator.

Log in as the "user" and set the Power Plan.  You should restart the computer after this.

Now log off and the Power Plan settings should stick. This works for me on customer computers - I sign out and the next day, move the mouse and the screen lights up (to be clear, the computer had not suspended).

I use the Windows 10 Settings to set this capability.

[image: Windows 10 Never Sleep]

Comment: Thank you for your response, i already did that but the syste. Still goes to sleep.

Comment: I am not sure why. I have used my method above many times. Try replacing the Power Driver with an upgraded version and also BIOS.